# PL/SQL Triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers, plsql

I am using these tables:

- flights (flno, origin, destination, distance, departs, arrives, price)
- aircraft (aid, aname, crusingrange)
- employees (eid, ename, salary)
- certified (eid,aid)

and I need to create a trigger that displays a warning when inserting an employee with "666" anywhere in his/her name.

This is what I came up with so far; I am lost with the rest of it.

```
set serveroutput on
create or replace trigger emp_warning
before insert
on employees
for each row
declare
 v_name;
begin
 select e.ename into v_ename
 from employees e
```

Comment: May be you could look up some examples in the manual. The "code" you came up with so far would not even compile.

Comment: I know it does not compile I am just learning it and I was stuck.

Comment: Then what is your question?

Comment: I finally figured it out thanks for you help. This my answer to the trigger question.

    set serveroutput on
    create or replace trigger name_warning
    before insert on employees
    for each row
    begin
    if :new.ename like '%666%' then
    dbms_output.put_line('Warning employees name contains 666');
    end if;
    end;
    /

Answer (score 1):

A trigger cannot "display a warning"; a trigger can raise an exception.

In the context of the body of a `before insert for each row` trigger, the value being supplied for the column is available from **`:NEW.columname`**

For example:

```
 BEGIN
    IF :NEW.ename LIKE '%666%' THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'ename contains ''666''.');
    END IF;
 END;
```

It's not mandatory that you use the `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`.  You could emit some line(s) using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`... the line could include whatever text you wanted, including the word "warning". But this isn't really a display of a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Use a check constraint instead of a trigger:

```
alter table empoloyees modify ename check (ename not like '%666%');
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out thanks for you help. This my answer to the trigger question.

```
set serveroutput on
create or replace trigger name_warning
before insert on employees
for each row
begin
if :new.ename like '%666%' then
dbms_output.put_line('Warning employees name contains 666');
end if;
end;
/
```